# /usr/bin/mail freezes and never sends. permissions?

Tags: php, email, shell

I'm trying to send mail through shell and it freezes. the script seems fine and i'm really confused. here it is in PHP:

```
$mail = '/usr/bin/mail -a 
    "Content-type: '.$header_content_type.';"
    -a "Reply-to: '.$header_reply_to.';"
    -a "List-Unsubscribe: '.$header_unsub.';"
    -s "'.$header_subject.'" "'.$email.'" < '.$myFile.'';
    exec($mail);
```

i echo'd everything to make sure it was pulling data into the variables and it was. when it executes, it freezes and does nothing. could this be a permissions error?

** EDIT **

i checked the mail log and saw an issue with virtual_alias_maps in the postfix main.cf
i made the necessary adjustments and it seems to work great. thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Question #1:

Can you execute the same command from the command line? Let's say instead of executing the command, what happens if you echoed `$mail` to the console. Then, copy the command, and then pasted it to a command prompt and hit enter?

### Question #2:

Why in the heck are you using the mail command and not the [PHP mailing function and modules](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). I'm just a dabbler in PHP, but I know that you can have PHP send mail out in a machine independent manner.

Comment: question #1 - yes i made sure to echo that first before i posted and it looked fine.

Comment: question #2 - i've been using the same line of code with the same mailing script for so many years and that was the way i had originally set it.

Comment: @john: Did you take the output of the echo and actually try to execute it on the command line? That will at least let you know if the problem is the /usr/bin/mail command or with PHP trying to exec /usr/bin/mail.

Answer (score 0):

Try using passthru() instead of exec() so the output prints.  Maybe that will expose the problem.

You probably have a reason for not using mail(), but I thought I'd mention it just in case.